# Ora más, ora menos

Tags: frase

I read the phrase "ora más ,ora menos" in El Mundo.

https://www.elmundo.es/album/yodona/belleza/2023/12/19/6581631fe85ece266b8b4595.html

The sentence is like this:

. Inés de la Fressange, un icono de la moda en su país y fuera de ella, que exporta su estilo chic con un corte de pelo corto, ora más, ora menos, que se ha convertido casi en su seña de identidad.

I believe "orar" means to pray but I can't find the word"ora" in the RAE.
I checked a previous post about the Mexican word "orale" but I'm not sure it is connected.

Comment: You know for translation into English, perhaps it's a good idea to trust an English speaker. Also, if you look at my examples, you will see it is very literary and can be followed by a noun or adjective.

Answer (score 2):

Ora is in the Diccionario de la Lengua Española, you may have misseed it when you searched for it:

[**ora**](https://dle.rae.es/ora)

1. conj. distrib. ahora. *Tomando ora la espada, ora la pluma.*
   Sin.:   ahora, bien.

Comment: A mi quedo claro que ora es ahora, pero qué significado tiene la frase? Creo que eso es lo más importante de la pregunta.

Comment: A pesar de cualquier diferencia ideológica, yo no estoy de acuerdo. ‘ora X, ora Y’ lo he oído varias veces. Pero ‘ahora X, ahora Y’ con el sentido de alternar posibilidades no lo escuché. Deberían haber puesto la definición en ‘ora’ en lugar de mandar el enlace a ‘ahora’, es mucho más común usar ‘ora’ con el sentido que se pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Hay que buscar en google por: **ora mas, ora meno**s y surgen una serie de documentos PDF, que contienen el termino.

No voy abrir cada PDF, perdóname.

Pero aqui va uno:

> Y por esto también ellos conservaban, *ora más, ora menos deformada*, [=a veces mas, a veces menos]
> la esperanza tradicional de que un Salvador habría de regenerar la
> humanidad sufridora y pecadora.
>
> [un texto sobre la religión](https://www.pliniocorreadeoliveira.info/ES_19381225_AdveniatRegnumTuum.htm)

English: For this reason also, they kept the traditional hope *in a more or less misguided way* that a Savior would have to give new life to suffering, sinning humanity.

Y aqui va otro:

> Más aun, entre los partidarios de luchar y resistir en casi todas las
> ocasiones solían  ser minoría los partidarios de hacerlo a ultranza y
> a toda costa, excepto en casos extremadamente desesperados y aunque a
> veces los partidarios de batirse sin  tregua ni cansancio consiguiesen
> *ganarse  a la mayoría *ora más ora menos breve o duraderamente**.
>
> [ora mas ora menos](https://www.piomoa.es/?p=13248)

English: [...] to win over the majority of supporters *in a briefer or more longer-lasting way*.

Pero va seguido **por un ajetivo o a veces un substantivo**.

Con substantivo:

> A caballo entre la «trascendencia orgánica» y sin olvidar nunca el
> racionalismo -ora más, ora menos- en su obra están presentes, muy
> diversas poéticas y un rigor suave pero firme, desde las primeras
> ideas -a veces una idea desencadenante como en Bruselas- hasta el
> diseño del detalle de un cierre, como en el Edificio Auxiliar del
> Banco de España en Madrid.
> [ora más, ora menos](https://ruc.udc.es/dspace/bitstream/handle/2183/5247/ETSA_17-1.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

English: [...] without ever forgetting the rationalism - at times more or less of it - that in his work very different poetic forms and mild but firm rigor is present in his work

Pues bien: su estilo chic con un corte de pelo corto, ora más,ora menos se puede expresar en inglés así:

English: her chic style with a short haircut, sometimes shorter sometimes longer

In **older** English, ora más ora menos largo [adjective] could have been expressed as: now shorter, now longer. But that "now" is not used like that in contemporary English. Otherwise, you take the adjective or noun and make it into an adjectival or noun phrase. The danger is thinking that this is **merely** **more or less x**, which it really isn't. And that's why Spanish uses it. It avoids saying *more or less x [adjective or noun]*.

Answer (score -2):

Lo ven? Es en parte por eso que soy Anti-RAE. Casi todo el mundo busca algo en el DLE, ven que no existe y ya se dan por vencidos. Si es por eso, prefiero el Wikcionario, tiene muchas más palabras y las definiciones son más precisas, detalladas, acertadas y actualizadas. Allí podemos [encontrar](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/ora):

> **ora**
>
> Conjunción distributiva
>
> 1    **Expresa posibilidades que se contraponen**, como alternancia en el tiempo o disyuntiva lógica.
>
> Uso: anticuado. 
> Sinónimos: ahora, bien, ya, sea (que). 
> Relacionados: o 
> Ejemplos: [▲]
>
> «Entiendo por hombre libre aquel que ciertamente conoce y se atiene a los móviles y fines de su conducta, ora abandonándose a la fluencia del instinto, ora guiándose por los cauces geométricos de la razón». Marañón, Gregorio (1990 [1919]). Ensayos sobre la vida sexual. Madrid: Espasa-Calpe.
>
> «La conjunción "ya" expresa alternabilidad así como la conjunción ora: ya saltando, ya corriendo; ora cante, ora ría». Manual de gramática de la lengua española, Cordón, 1944, p. 238.

En tu caso, ‘ora más, ora menos’ sería: **‘ya sea algún detalle más (que no debería haberse mencionado) o algún detalle menos (que falte mencionar)’**, o también **‘y sin importar lo que falte  o lo que se dijo de más de la modelo’**.

**Posdata**:

La información en internet sobra. Yo soy hincha del Wikcionario y de los demás diccionarios abiertos a pesar de que digan que en esas páginas ‘cualquiera puede poner cualquier cosa’. En la práctica, rara vez sucede y las contribuciones están fuertemente controladas.

La RAE tiene su repertorio distribuido de forma algo irregular entre el DLE, el Diccionario de Americanismos y el Diccionario Histórico. Pero además hay diversas fuentes que también son ‘oficiales’: el [DEM](https://dem.colmex.mx), el [NEOMA](https://www.um.es/neologismos/index.php/), e incluso la [BBVA](https://www.fbbva.es/diccionario) hizo su propio diccionario. En este último, también aparecen definiciones similares para [ora](https://www.fbbva.es/diccionario/ora/).

El Wikcionario recopiló una larga lista de [diccionarios](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikcionario:Recursos) para consultar.  Y sino, una búsqueda en Google del significado capaz vaya bien. Hasta ahora, todos los intentos de armar un único diccionario que unifique todas las palabras y significados que pudieren haber han fracasado. Qué le vamos a hacer...

Y sí, pido disculpas si la posdata es casi toda la respuesta es la posdata. Pero es importante que acá **la gente aprenda a pescar, además de recibir los peces**. Un saludo.

Comment: A pesar de su diatriba (diatriba: Discurso o escrito acre y violento contra alguien o algo.) contra la RAE, **ora** si figura en el Diccionario de la Lengua: https://dle.rae.es/ora : 1. conj. distrib. ahora. *Tomando ora la espada, ora la pluma.*

Comment: Lo sé y nunca dije que no. PEro está presentado de un modo confuso y el OP podría haber consultado en más lugares antes de preguntar

Comment: Very useful links to other dictionary sources. It is all good

Comment: OK. So it seems to mean sometimes less, sometimes more or other variables. Is it very formal or can it be used in everyday speech ? I mean would it sound odd?

Comment: @Bluelion7 El término es formal, aunque un poco viejo o anticuado. A veces lo escucho más que nada de personas mayores. En el diccionario dice que también se usa la construcción ‘ahora X, ahora Y’  con un sentido similar pero yo nunca lo oí con ese sentido. En cambio, ‘ora X, ora Y’ sí lo he escuchado.

Comment: @Bluelion7 En general, lo más usual que se escucha es la construcción ‘ya sea X, ya sea Y’ o ‘ya sea X o Y’, como sinónimo de ‘either X or Y’.

Comment: Es literario. No es de "gente mayor".

Comment: Tiene sentido de ser literario ,como dije viene de ''El Mundo''. Por eso, a veces,tengo dudas de utilizar palabras de periodicos porque muy a menudo son rebuscados para el espanol de la calle.